# How can I diff two branches with fugitive?

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

In fugitive I can get the git status in a new window by `:Gstatus` and in that window to <kbd>D</kbd> on a file to get the diff in a new split.

It is also possible to get all versions of a file using `:Glog` and I can load all previous commits with `:Glog --`.

What I would like to do is to get a **Gstatus** window for the diff of two branches. For example my **topic** and **development** branch so I can diff all files that have changed.

Is it possible to get a *interactive* window with all the files that changed between two commits?

Comment: As ZyX mentions, it might be handy to add a command to fugitive to pull `git diff --name-status {REV1}..{REV2}` into a window. Or maybe there's some better workflow... will star and watch for any wizardry.

Comment: Note: This was also opened as [fugitive GitHub issue #270](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/270) - Tim Pope replied with a workaround `:Git diff branch1 branch2 --`. This is not ideal though as it just shows a standard diff output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As git does not support mercurial/bazaar status between two revisions neither fugitive can do it. Git has `git diff --name-status` instead, but simple grep reveals that this feature is never used in fugitive, except for checking of some file being clean (i.e. unmodified) when doing `:Gw` and friends.

---

If you are not afraid of somewhat experimental code, then you can try my [aurum](https://gitlab.com/ZyX-I/aurum), it can bring you status window with

```
AuStatus rev topic wdrev development
```

and see vimdiff of specific file with `C` (closes status window by default, use `let g:aurum_statwincmd='k'` to avoid).

Note: with hg-git and vim compiled with +python aurum will be using more stable code as mercurial is the primary VCS I use.

---

Another idea is using vcscommand, mercurial/bazaar and hg-git/bzr-git. Then status will be viewed with

```
VCSStatus -r topic -r development
```

(mercurial, don’t remember how to do it in bazaar). I am unfamiliar with vcscommand though, so can’t say whether it offers as many interactive features in status buffer as fugitive or aurum do (seems it does not: `nmap <buffer>` in git status buffer shows nothing). The above code should work according to the documentation, but I have not tested.

Comment: Did you move [aurum](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum) somewhere else? Its been deleted now

Comment: @icc97 I have update link in the answer: it was moved to gitlab since I have not found a good free mercurial hosting. Note though aurum was not maintained for quite a few years already.

Comment: I maintain a [list of github alternatives](https://github.com/ianchanning/awesome-github-alternatives) and there's a few mercurial ones listed on there - I hear good things about https://sourcehut.org/

Answer (score 2):

As per [Tim Pope's comment on the related fugitive GitHub issue #270](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/270#issuecomment-1115743273) fugitive doesn't handle this and has no plans to.

However in searching this I came across [Merginal](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal/) which is based on Fugitive:

> Merginal aims provide a nice inteface for dealing with Git branches.  It
> offers interactive TUI for:
>
> - Viewing the list of branches
> - Checking out branches from that list
> - Creating new branches
> - Deleting branches
> - Merging branches
> - Rebasing branches
> - Solving merge conflicts
> - Renaming branches
> - Viewing git history for branches
>
> ...
>
> Merginal is based on Fugitive, so it requires Fugitive.

What it doesn't quite make clear is that you can do a `git diff` between two branches.

After you have installed Merginal assuming you have `main` (`master`) branch and you want to diff `develop` branch against it to see the changes you are about to merge in Vim:

1. `:Git checkout main`
2. `:Merginal`
3. You should see something like this in the left panel:

   ```
   Press ? for help

     develop
   * master
   ```
4. Move your cursor over the develop branch

   1. If you look in the help `?`

      ```
      gd   Open diff files buffer to diff
           against the branch under the
           cursor.
      ```
5. Type `gd` (similar to any Fugitive command)
6. This should should produce something like this in the left panel:

   ```
   Press ? for help

   === Diffing With: ===
   develop
   =====================

   M   README.md
   ```
7. Then as with Fugitive you can press `dv` with the cursor over the file and it will open a vertical `diffsplit`:

[image: Vim vertical diffsplit of README.md]